# Storm Exactly once processing

Tags: apache-storm, azure-eventhub

I am trying to develop a hybrid topology of Apache Storm to consume from EventHub via `EventHubSpout`. I have seen a few examples, but nowhere I am able to find a sample that shows me how to consume data using `EventHubSpout` and be able to debug my other bolts which receive the stream from this spout. The problem is I want to be able to debug my C# Bolt code in Local Environment.